# Approximate match function for numerics

Tags: r, numeric

I have a vector of numbers:

```
[1]  96.500  96.625  96.750  96.875  97.000  97.125  97.250  97.375  97.500  97.625  97.750  97.875  98.000
[14]  98.125  98.250  98.375  98.500  98.625  98.750  98.875  99.000  99.125  99.250  99.375  99.500  99.625
[27]  99.750  99.875 100.000 100.125 100.250 100.375 100.500
```

I want to take a different number, `99.49`, and find the index numbers for which values in the vector it lies between. In this instance I would want it to return `c(24, 25)` as the number of interest is between 99.375 and 99.5.

Anyone know an easy way to do this (one or two lines of code) in R? Assume that the number of interest can be in the vector. I currently have a "while" loop, but trying to see if there is an simpler vectorized format.

Comment: Probably you're looking for `findInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

with x being your vector and v the given number this function would do

`between <- function(x, v) {
  c(max(which(x <= v)), min(which(x >= v)))
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient version of `match` working on numeric data. Efficient because my C++ implementation is short-circuiting and finishes the search after the first match has been found. Maybe I overlooked something, but I really think such a function is missing in base R, and I once in a while stumble across this problem.

Note however that depending on the problem, first sorting your target vector (as well as your vector to be matched) might be much more efficient and `findInterval` as suggested in the comments is the way to go.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
IntegerVector match_dbl_cpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector table,
                        int nomatch, double tolerance) {

  int n = x.size();
  int m = table.size();
  IntegerVector out(n, nomatch);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < m) {
      if (std::abs(x[i] - table[j]) < tolerance) {
        out[i] = j + 1;
        break;
      }
      ++j;
    }
  }
  return out;
}
')

match_dbl <- function(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_,
                      tolerance = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) {

  if (!is.integer(nomatch))
    stop("'nomatch' must be an integer'")

  if (!is.numeric(tolerance) || tolerance <= 0.0)
    stop("'tolerance' must be a positive number")

  match_dbl_cpp(x, table, nomatch, tolerance)
}

# generate some random numeric data
set.seed(123)
table <- runif(1000L)
table <- sample(c(table, table)) # 'table' now contains duplicates
x <- sample(table, 100L)

m1 <- match(x, table)
m1_dbl <- match_dbl(x, table)
identical(m1, m1_dbl) # TRUE according to expectation
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(match(x, table),
                               match_dbl(x, table)) # speed is fine
Unit: microseconds
            expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
 match(x, table) 45.622 48.6295 52.54944 49.5540 53.995 129.079   100
 match_dbl(x, table) 46.380 48.9325 53.13952 49.6335 52.054 106.160   100

# minimally disturb x
x <- x + runif(n = length(x), min = -1e-10, max = 1e-10)

identical(m1, match(x, table)) # now FALSE
[1] FALSE 
identical(m1_dbl, match_dbl(x, table)) # still TRUE
[1] TRUE
identical(m1_dbl, match_dbl(x, table, tolerance = 1e-11)) # also FALSE now
[1] FALSE
```

A version of `%in%` for numeric data can then easily be written as:

```
`%in_dbl%` <- function(x, table) match_dbl(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
```

Suggestions for improvements are warmly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
z = scan(nmax = 33)
96.500  96.625  96.750  96.875  97.000  97.125  97.250  97.375  97.500  97.625  97.750  97.875  98.000
98.125  98.250  98.375  98.500  98.625  98.750  98.875  99.000  99.125  99.250  99.375  99.500  99.625
99.750  99.875 100.000 100.125 100.250 100.375 100.500 \n

btw <- function(data, num){
c(min(which(num<data))-1, min(which(num<data)))
}

btw(data = z, num = 99.49)
```